# How to use dynamic values in items attribute of <form:select> tag in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

please help on the below scenario,

```
form:select path="${field.fieldDetails.fieldName}
items="${field.fieldDetails.fieldName}"--> this is not working
```

If I give

```
 items="${country}"-->it's working
```

The `field.fieldDetails.fieldName` is not an constant values it will changes (Country,department,etc). Is there any possibilities to use the expressions

Comment: <form:select path="${field.fieldDetails.fieldName}" items="${field.fieldDetails.fieldName}"></form:select>

Comment: you need to pass path of entity in select path attribute and pass items into select option

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, that path and items values will be dynamic, will come from database.